# In Android how can I disable a Listener for a while after an event has been caught?

Tags: android, listener

For example:

```
private final SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
      // pseudo code
      if (it is a shake event) {
         output some text;
      }
   }
}
```

I have implemented a `SensorEventListener`, but the shake events are detected directly one after another. What can I do to make the listener rest for a while after a shake event is detected and some text is output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either disable the click listener by setting it to null, or keep track of the time the last shake was processed:

```
private final SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

   private Date lastShaked;

   @Override
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
      // pseudo code
      if (lastShaked + some time < now) {
         lastShaked = now;
         output some text;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried your lastShaked method and it works ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
sensorManager.unregisterListener(mySensorEventListener,sensor);
```

For more info refer this link [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#unregisterListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor%29)

Answer (score 0):

To disable listener(for example OnClickListener from some object), use:

```
object.setOnClickListener(null);
```

If you need to enable listener again, use:

```
object.setOnClickListener(YourActivity.this);
```

After a shake, disable the listener till some event happens, and enable the listener in that event again.